# Twitter Bootstrap Affix: disappears under the footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, affix

I'm trying to use Affix, but I have some problem: when I scroll down - my affix div partially disappears under the footer, here is a [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/UmEvUPA/2) and [code](http://jsbin.com/UmEvUPA/2/edit). How can I prevent this?

`data-offset-bottom="anynumber"` - don't work.

Comment: If you look at the docs on GetBootstrap.com they use the affix with a sidebar and footer and there's many settings in the script and there's css within the breakpoints too. Take that a part to learn how to accomplish what you want. Here's the script they wrote for that, notice the .bs-footer and then look at the css for that too. http://getbootstrap.com/docs-assets/js/application.js

Comment: The offset must be calculated like this example: http://bootply.com/102441

Answer (score 1):

This looks more like a `z-index` problem. I believe you can fix this by applying higher `z-index` value to the `.affix` than the footer using CSS.

Example:

set `z-index` if not set

`yourFooter { position:absolute/relative/fixed /* a positioning is a must */ ; z-index: 300 }`

then simply add a higher z-index to the `.affix` div. **It already has a fixed positioning** so there's no need to set the `position` for this.

**Notes:** While calculating z-index, test it with everything first, make sure that the affix does not start appearing above your `modals` and others.

Hope this works.